# Saving an uploaded file from an ajax form

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

Its been a long time since i used php and i need some help regarding this basic function.

```
{
        $msg .= " File Name: " . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] . ", ";
        $msg .= " File Size: " . @filesize($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);

        @unlink($_FILES['fileToUpload']);       
}
```

Suppose i have a file in the `$_FILES['fileToUpload']`, how do i create an upload dir if it does not exist, and save the file there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use is_dir() to check if the directory exitst    http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

then use mkdir()     if it doesn't exist   http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: this is correct, but i will still need the `move_uploaded_file()` function as well